# How was the new SE arbitrator selected?

Tags: discussion, terms-of-service, arbitration-clause

I was just reading through the arbitration clause (sec. 10b) of the [new Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) ([related MSE announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)) and saw two references to "JAMS INC."

That name is never explained in the document itself, but the top result I get for a search on "JAMS INC arbitration" is [this arbitration company](https://www.jamsadr.com/). Is that the JAMS to which the ToS refers? (I can't imagine the answer is "no", but I just want to be clear.)

And of greater interest, how/why did the company choose JAMS rather than, say, the American Arbitration Association (an organization mentioned in the Terms as a backup option) or another competitor? I'm not endorsing or complaining about anyone here, I simply want to understand the thought process. And I want to give the company every opportunity to put itself in a better light before I make a final decision on how I feel about this.

Comment: "another competitor" not sure there is such a thing— all terms I've seen that have mandatory arbitration seem to pick one of those two, or sometimes allow whoever is raising the complaint to pick.

Comment: Yeah, there doesn't seem to be much competition. I could find two alternatives without putting in more effort than it's worth: [the International Chamber of Commerce](https://iccwbo.org/dispute-resolution-services/arbitration/) and [the International Institute for Conflict Prevention & Resolution](https://www.cpradr.org/dispute-resolution-services/services-offered).